# Open Specific Linux Port

Tags: debian, iptables, linux-networking

Im trying to open a Port(2012) on my VPS so i can access it over the internet.

This is the output of *sudo iptables -L* produces

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere          anywhere             multiport dports ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8     reject-with icmp-port-      
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2012
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5    LOG    level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Nmap discovers just ports 25,22 and 80. Please what might i be doing wrong?

Edit :

`netstat -anp | grep :2012` show this :

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep :2012
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2012          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15303/X-engine
```

Comment: Are you sure service listening on port 2012 is started ? provide `netstat -anp | grep :2012`

Comment: show `iptables-save -c` , `lsof -i :2012` and `netstat -tan`  output

Comment: @val0x00ff these are the outputs - http://pastebin.com/WXgabCEL

Comment: @krisFR this is the output - http://pastebin.com/qNzgcee6

Comment: @dev Line `37` and `44` are the same. Then on line `38` you've fail2-ban  which will do nothing if your sshd runs on port `2012`  Then, where is the output of `lsof -i :2012`.  Also Can you show the output of `grep -E '(^Port|[^#]ListenAddress)' /etc/ssh/sshd_config` And as KrisFR is suggesting, `sshd` is running on the loopback address which is not routable. You've probably set `ListenAddress` in sshd_config

Comment: @val0x00ff Are you sure you posted this on the right "thread" ?

Comment: @krisFR I think I did. I replied based on the pastebin.com paste. But I think you already provided the answer. It's the `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @val0x00ff, Thank You for your inputs.Working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service listening on port 2012 is only listening on localhost (127.0.0.1).

This is not routable.

Make it listen on server's IPV4 (or IPV6).

Answer (score 1):

By default nmap probes only the 1000 most often used ports. If you want to scan a specific port, use nmap like this:

```
nmap ... -p2012 ...
```